# How do I print the difference of a tuple in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I want to output difference two tuple and remove one element on tuple

```
a = [(1,2),(2,3),(3,3)]
if (1,2) in a:
       ## how to remove (1,2) on tuple
```

i need output `[(2,3),(3,3)]` how to do it?

Thanks,

Comment: Lists have a handy `remove` method.

Comment: Check `remove` method of a list

Comment: Thanks also if i have a = [(0911,1),(0936,1),(0911,2),(0911,3)] i need [(0911,1),(0911,2),(0911,3)] output how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other way, you can use `del`

```
>>> a = [(1,2),(2,3),(3,3)]
>>> del a[a.index((1,2))]
>>> a
[(2, 3), (3, 3)]
>>>
```

or using .pop

```
>>> a = [(1,2),(2,3),(3,3)]
>>> a.pop(a.index((1,2)))
(1, 2)
>>> a
[(2, 3), (3, 3)]
>>>
```

Comment: if i have a = [(0911,1),(0936,1),(0911,2),(0911,3)] so i need [(0911,1),(0911,2),(0911,3)] output how?

Comment: `del a[a.index((936,1))]`

Answer (score 6):

You can simply use `.remove` method for lists when you know the element that is to be removed.

```
>>> a = [(1,2),(2,3),(3,3)]
>>> a.remove((1,2))
>>> a
[(2, 3), (3, 3)]
```